# How to comment in-line CSS?

Tags: css, comments

As per the title, how do I comment an inline css property?
 like **height** in:

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:30%;">
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple like C++

```
<div style="width:100%; /* height:30%;*/">
```

[SEE W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

Comment: Hehe at east you got it right :-p but W3Schools ... is a bit old fashioned ^^

Comment: Well I may be wrong but I'll let the community answer :) (if they bother to)

Comment: Personally I think w3schools is a great resource. It's extremely good for beginners to grips with all sorts, particularly with the 'tryit' feature.

Comment: See http://www.w3fools.com/ --- don't misunderstand me, I don't want to be rude, the info is good at w3schools but ...

Comment: I love W3schools and since your answer is equivalent to the others', I'm glad to accept it :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="width:100%; /*height:30%;*/">
```

Other answers don't comment `height` as requested :)

Source : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments)

Edit : If I may add something useful, if you are not *forced* to use inline styles, avoid them and use a proper CSS stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="width:100%; height:30%; /*comment*/">
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div style="width: 100%; /* height: 30% */"></div>
```